# Вместо переменной выводит <built-in function next>

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Эта часть кода должна выводить переменную  next, а выводит built-in function next.
Также, если вы знаете как сделать так, чтобы код просил цифру, пока она не будет введена, проще, то буду признателен)

```
def f():
    try:
        next = int(raw_input("> "))
    except:
        f()
    return next

    def gold_room():
        print "This room is full of gold. How much do you take?"
        f()
        print next

    gold_room()
```

Comment: `next` - это встроенный метод в языке Python для получения следующего значения генератора. Поменяйте название вашей переменной на что-нибудь другое.

Comment: next это имя встроенной функции. Переименуйте перменную.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Кстати, если вам нужно где-то лайк или плюсик поставить, то отпишитесь)

Answer (score 2):

Про смену имени переменной next уже написали. По второй части вопроса:

> Также, если вы знаете как сделать так, чтобы код просил цифру, пока она не будет введена, проще, то буду признателен)

Я так понимаю, что нужно что-то типа такого:

```
while True:
    a = input('>')
    try:
        a = int(a)
        break
    except:
        print('Enter a number!')
```